# Css of node-modules

Tags: css, webpack, node-modules, css-loader

I am using css modules in my react application. After setting `modules:true` in`webpack.config.js`, I am able to get css from files which I created in my src folder. I am importing some components from node-modules. But the css of components present in node-modules is not getting applied.

I also tried importing css of node-modules using import 'path'; but it didnt work.

If I set `modules:false`, css of node-modules is getting applied and css of files in src folder is not getting applied.

```js
webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: All css imported from node modules are not working? or you can't override them?

Comment: This shouldn't occur since you importing styles from node modules like: import "path"  without assigning them to any object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to the node module you are using may not be following module syntax. I mean they might be setting classes directly with a string instead of using like `style.someClassName`. So, you need 2 entries in your rules 1 for your stuff and 1 for node modules.

for ex:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        modules: true,
                    },
                }
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        modules: false,
                    },
                }
            ],
        }],
    },
  };
```